# Return a Row Value given some Conditions in Rows

Tags: r, filter, subset

When I subset data, I either subet based on some values or across a group of rows as follows:

```
# Subset on some values
df<-df[df$A=='some values',]
# Subset on Group of Rows
df<-df[1:10,]
```

However, Is there a way to combine these two methods?

I need to be able to get the first 7 rows of a dataframe, then search over a column with conditions, and return a value in a different column.

So if I have this data:

```
col_with_conditions<-c(1,2,3,4,5,1,2,3,4,5)
col_to_return<-c(10,10,10,20,20,20,10,20,10,20)
df<-data.frame(col_with_conditions,col_to_return)
col_with_conditions col_to_return
             1            10
             2            10
             3            10
             4            20
             5            20
             1            20
             2            10
             3            20
             4            10
             5            20
```

I would like to search for values 1 and 2, then return the first value in `col_to_return`. In this example, the code would return `10.`

Another example:

```
col_with_conditions<-c(5,2,2,3,4,5)
col_to_return<-c(20,10,10,10,20,10)
df<-data.frame(col_with_conditions,col_to_return)
```

would return `10` as well.

Another example:

```
col_with_conditions<-c(5,2,4,3,4)
col_to_return<-c(20,20,20,10,20)
df<-data.frame(col_with_conditions,col_to_return)
```

would return `20.`

However, this example:

```
col_with_conditions<-c(5,3,4,3,4)
col_to_return<-c(20,20,20,10,20)
df<-data.frame(col_with_conditions,col_to_return)
```

should return `NA` which I can convert to `0` elsewhere. Sometimes the dataframe won't always have those values of `1 or 2.`

Is this possiable to do in one step?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be

```
df$col_to_return[df$col_with_conditions[1:7] %in% c(1, 2)][1]
#[1] 10
```

This would also take care when there is no value that matches the conditon and it will return `NA`.

Comment: Okay. Thanks you. However, it doesn't look at the first seven rows. If it is a larget dataframe then it still picks up the `1` or `2` which I would not like.

Comment: @JackArmstrong It should not matter actually , since you are taking first value of `col_to_return` however, I have updated the answer to take care of only first 7 rows.

Comment: The `[1:7]` needs to be in there for my objective. Without it, the code will serach over the entire dataframe it filtered. So if a value of `1` or `2` is in position `[8,1]` then your original code would return the value in position `[8,2]`

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` for readability:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  head(7) %>% 
  filter(col_with_conditions %in% c(1, 2)) %>% 
  .$col_to_return %>% 
  .[1]
```

should return what you are after.